# A page returns 200 instead of 401 when login is required

Tags: java, http

I am tasked with checking whether some URLs are working correctly, I'm using Java to make HTTP get request to get the response code.

So what I did was this.

```
URL u = new URL("some URL");
HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
huc.connect();
int code = huc.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(code + " " + huc.getURL());
```

**The Problem:** Some sites require you to login to access the page, but the page doesn't return a 401 code, but 200. Note that the web page doesn't show up until a username and password are provided. It asks for authentication in a pop up window.

So how do I catch these kind of links?

Also, how can I identify if a webpage shows a login page like http://www.example.com/login/? Is it sufficient to just check the URL for the word “login”?

Comment: Well, if the page requires you to log in, it still exists, no?

Comment: If you have to deal with pages that roll their own custom authentication, then it follows that you probably have to write your own custom code to accommodate them.  Depending on how the relevant sites work, you might be able to bypass authentication by sending an appropriate cookie in your request, as if you had already authenticated, or by some similar means.

Comment: @5gon12eder yeah but my supervisor asked to know which sites needs authentication to access them

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have little knowledge in web programming so i will try to look for more info regardng  ur suggestion. Thank you

Comment: I'm confused - the "login" page **should** return 200 - you can get to it without being logged in.  Something **behind** the login page should return a 401.  I don't think that this method will work the way you'd like.

Comment: @stdunbar - if the page is using basic auth it will return a 401 (and browser can interpret that by prompting for credentials). Any sane website actually used by customers will likely use something more than this though.

Comment: @stdunbar so even if the page isnt loaded i will still get a 200?! My problem was with a website that shows a pop up window only. It doesnt show the webpage until i enter the username and password... Maybe I misunderstood the 401 error, is it returned when authentication is required or after the credentials are entered?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no universal way to deal with this. You have to know how the site you're using does authentication - 401? separate login page? multi-factor auth (ie: using RSA token)?  Checking for the substring "login" in the URL is a possible way of handling some, but not enough for a general way.

For example, a 401 will only happen when using [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (or when trying to access protected resources directly).  There's a lot of other ways to do auth

[John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) sums up the issue quite well in his comment:

> If you have to deal with pages that roll their own custom authentication, then it follows that you probably have to write your own custom code to accommodate them. Depending on how the relevant sites work, you might be able to bypass authentication by sending an appropriate cookie in your request, as if you had already authenticated, or by some similar means

Comment: I think i have a better understanding of the issue now. Thank you :)